# Kubernetes pod Rollback and Restart

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

[image]Deployment resource object is still not supported in our cluster and not enabled.
We are using Pod resource object Yaml file. something like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sample-test
  namespace: default
spec:
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  containers:
```

I have explored patch and Put rest api for Pod(Kubectl patch and replace) - it will update to new image version and pod restarts.

I need help in below:

1. When the image version is same, it will not update and pod will not restart.
   How can i acheive Pod restart, is there any API for this or any alternate
   approach for this. Because  My pod also refers configmap and secret. After i
   make changes to secret, i want to restart pod so that it can take updated
   value.
2. Suppose when patch applied with new container image and it fails status is failed, I want to rollback to previous version, How can i acheive this with standalone pod without using deployment. Is there any alternate approach.

Comment: Why is that you are using such a older version of K8s, where deployment is not supported?

Answer (score -1):

Achieving solutions for your scenario, can be handled like this:

> When the image version is same, it will not update and pod will not restart. How can i acheive Pod restart, is there any API for this or any alternate approach for this. Because My pod also refers configmap and secret. After i make changes to secret, i want to restart pod so that it can take updated value

Create a new secret/configmap each time and update the pod yaml to use the new configmap/secret rather than the old name.

> Suppose when patch applied with new container image and it fails status is failed, I want to rollback to previous version, How can i acheive this with standalone pod without using deployment. Is there any alternate approach

Before you do a Pod update, get the current Pod yaml using kubectl like this,

`kubectl get pod <pod-name> -o yaml -n <namespace>`

After getting the yaml, generate the new pod yaml and apply it. In case of failure, clean up the new resources created(configmaps & secrets) and apply the older version of pod to achieve rollback

Comment: I would say taking each and evey resource yaml. Get all yaml from the all the resources ```kubectl get all -o yaml > getall.yaml``` would be easier isn't it? the modify the required one

Comment: When we use patch/put rest api(kubectl patch/replace) - we cannot change configmap and secrets names in volumes of the pod. I guess only containers images can be updated. Below is the snapshot of pod.

Comment: apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    image: repository/large:1.2
    name: test
    ports:
    - containerPort: 443
      hostPort: 443
      name: https
      protocol: TCP
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test/secrets
      name: test-secrets
  hostname: test
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: testrepo-pull
  nodeName: test
  volumes:
  - name: test-secrets
    secret:
      defaultMode: 256
      secretName: test-secret1

Comment: Update the pod yaml in the question. It is difficult to view in the comment

Comment: Attached is the snapshot of yaml in question above

Comment: Why can'y you use the `kubectl apply` command to achieve what I described above?